# Cross-browser javascript to get and replace exact HTML from a user's selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, range

I'm looking for a way to get, modify, and replace the HTML from a user's selected range using javascript or JQuery. Basically, imagine the user selects a range across some HTML tags (the | delineate the selection):

```
<p>This is an <b>example |of</b> some text| to be selected</p>
```

How would I get:

```
of</b> some text
```

Then further, after running some code to make a modification to that text:

```
of some</b> altered text
```

How would I plug it back in such that the final version reads:

```
<p>This is an <b>example of some</b> altered text to be selected</p>
```

I haven't been able to solve either problem, finding the exact html of a range, or writing specific modified HTML to a range.

Comment: Are you are trying to reinsert the altered text within the same document it was taken from?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The altered text will go back into the same document, replacing the selected text.

Comment: Where would the altered text come from to replace the selected text?

Comment: I would just be modifying the text in my code, with something like: function () { var html = getSelectionHTML(); html = transformHTML(html); replaceHTML(html); } What I need to figure out is how the getSelectionHTML() and replaceHTML() functions would work.

Comment: What kind of transformation are planning to perform on the HTML?

Comment: I'm thinking I'll wrap it in HTML tags with some classes. I've seen your rangy library and want to do something similar in terms of highlighting text, wrapping in span tags with a highlight class, or linking the selected text. I'm building a chrome extension and one of the Rangy modules fails to load, so I was looking for a quicker solution to do roughly the same thing, without digging into the Rangy code.

Comment: Right. If Rangy is failing to load in a Chrome extension, I would like to to fix it, so it would useful if you could post a bug report or question on the discussion group. I know it has been used successfully in a Chrome extension: http://feltipen.com/

Comment: Cool, I'll submit a bug report, and maybe a patch if I can track down the problem. After looking into this a little more, Rangy seems like easily the best way to tackle this problem. Thanks for making it available.

Comment: @Travis - I posted an answer that my offer you an alternative solution. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

This is my start:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/BSrSc/)

It replaces text selected with the input's value.

It doesn't take into consideration html though.

Any thoughts on that?

```
$('#content').on('mouseup',function() {

    var t = false;

    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    if (t && (t+'').length > 0) {

       $('#content').html($('#content').html().replace(t,$('input').val()))

        alert("You replaced:\n" + t + "\nwith:\n" + $('input').val());
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I deviated from your text selection idea and did a mouseover & highlight based solution. Not your exact requirements, but it accomplishes your basic goals. Lots of room for improvement.

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bd2c6/1/)

JS

```
var $txtArea = $('textarea'); 

function Rebind(){
    $('#editable *').off('mouseover.editor').on('mouseover.editor',function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        return false; 
    }).off('mouseout.editor').on('mouseout.editor',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        return false; 
    }).off('click.editor').on('click.editor',function() {
        var $sel = $('.highlight'); 
        $txtArea.val($sel.html()).data('selected', $sel);
    });
}
Rebind();
$('input').click(function(){
    $txtArea.data('selected').html($txtArea.val()); 
    Rebind();
}); 
​
```

*NOTE: For whatever reason [jQuery's `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was not picking up the new elements so I needed to Rebind them after edits.*

HTML

```
<div id='editable'>
    <div>
        This is <br /> some <b>content</b>
        <div>testing</div>
        <div> 
            some <i>more content</i>
            <div>eidt me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<textarea ></textarea>
<input type="button" value="save" /> ​
```

CSS

```
textarea{
 height:150px;
 width:100%;    
}

.highlight
{
    border:1px solid blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think one way to achieve this would be:

1. get the highest element in the DOM which contains the whole
   selection
2. Parse its innerHTML for the selection (no regex please)
3. display the match and remember its position and the element for inserting back the edited version

Although I step 3 likely won't work to actually change the layout. There should hopefully be easier solutions.

Comment: For your #2 - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the exact same thing, to just remember its position and insert it back

Comment: This works for most cases, unless the selection's text appears more than once in the parent DOM element. In that case, how would I tell which instance needed to be replaced?

Comment: @BrandonBoone I have heard RegEx is horrible and I hate having to touch it myself. Unfortunately, until now all I've read is people discussing why not to use it, but no actual tutorials on how I can do it properly in JS. (I admit I haven't actively searched either as luckily I very rarely need these kind of things). Suggestions welcome :-)

Comment: @Armatus I agree also, I hear not to use it but never hear of any alternatives

Comment: @Armatus & JamesFair. For parsing HTML, my favorites are jQuery (on the server using node.js) or the HTMLAgilityPack (on the server using C#). http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/. I've also heard of others using XSLT to extract data as long as the html is xhtml compliant.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my take though, like iambriansreed's version, it doesn't account for HTML, as you'll see in the example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/793N3/1/)

Here's the important code:

```
var s = window.getSelection();
var ss = s.toString();
var node = $(s.getRangeAt(0).startContainer).parent();
var contents = node.text();
var idx = contents.indexOf( ss );
node.html( contents.substr( 0, idx ) + 
    "HELLO" + 
    contents.substr( idx+ss.length ) );
```

Comment: Is this cross browser friendly?

Comment: It was only intended to be a proof-of-concept and a start in the right direction.  I'm sure it's not cross-browser friendly.